# How i fix missing assembly reference for Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;

Tags: windows-phone-7, assemblies, scheduler

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;
```

The type or namespace name 'Scheduler' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have tried reinstalling all the sdks and everything but for some reason cant use the Scheduler class that everyone else can with the new mango update.

---

ok. i tried this and i found in the properties that it is set to version 7.0 but i dont see and upgrade option. does this mean that i havnt installed the sdk properly?

Edit: OK, went to re install the sdk and apparently it didn't install first time cause i didn't have vs service pack 1 installed. gonna install that then try re installing.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your project is still targeting version 7.0.
This namespace is not supported in 7.0.

To upgrade a project right click it in the Solution Explorer and select the upgrade option.
Or view the projects properties windows and upgrade there.